# How to use a DVI/HDMI monitor with Mac Mini's DisplayPort?

Tags: mac, hdmi, dvi, mac-mini

If I buy a Mac Mini, how can I use it with my Dell monitor?  The Dell does **not** have a DisplayPort, only DVI and HDMI.

I was looking at the Mac Minis and noticed they don't have DVI or VGA ports.  Does the Mac Mini come with any kind of an adapter that will allow me to use my existing Dell monitor?

Thanks in advance for your help, I'm going to start researching this question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac Mini comes with a Mini-DVI to DVI connector. So it sounds like your Dell monitor would work as it stands

Answer (score 1):

Go read the [specs page](http://www.apple.com/macmini/specs.html) for current mac minis. In the "Graphics and video support" it lists a Mini-DVI port (not Display Port) and under the "In the box" section it lists "Mini-DVI to DVI Adapter".

You should have no trouble connecting a mac mini to your Dell monitor.